# How to save value , when user deleted cookie and page has been refreshed

Tags: javascript, cookies, onload, page-refresh

I need to make my cookies undeletable by saving the value. I mean , if I deleted cookie in browser then I refreshed page, the value shouldn't be changed from current to 1 .It must be saved and continue counts like nothing happened.

```js
 var startButton = document.getElementById('start-button');
 
 var counterAttemps = 0;
 var maxAttemps = 10;
 
 
 function ad(){
        
        
        value = getCookie("counterAttemps");
      
      
        vl = parseInt(value , 10);
        vl = vl + counterAttemps;
        if(vl >= 1){
       counterAttemps = vl;
      
        }
        
    }
   
  
    function checkCookie(){
        
        ad();
    
    
    }
    
    
     startButton.onclick = function(){

if(counterAttemps < maxAttemps){
    
    setCookie("counterAttemps" , counterAttemps , 1);

            }
           
                 
               counterAttemps++;
            } 

    
            window.onload = checkCookie();
```

Comment: You can't protect cookies from being deleted using only JS. You must remember that it's the user who has full control over the browser and its settings - your code can use or alter only a small part of it. If you want to store values outside users' control, you should use an external storage e.g. a database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll have to store the user session externally with a server.  Unfortunately the user has ultimate control over his/her browser cookies.